# PHP __construct not taking variables

Tags: php, oop

I can't seem to find a answer for that, maybe somebody here can help me.

I'm trying to pass in a `database` connection in the `construct` of my `class` but i'm getting an error `"Missing argument 1 for item::__construct() "` ,

I'v tried setting it with a setter method it works perfectly, so i know the `variable` with the `database` connection is right.

I'v tried to pass in the `constructor` plain text, like `$item = new item('abc')` and then I'm getting it perfectly.

The reason I want it in the constructor is because its a `database` connection so I'll always need it.

In `index.php` the code is not in a class so the problem cannot be the scope.

Here is the code.
index.php.

```
$dbh = new dbh;
$item = new item($dbh);
```

item.php

```
<?php
class item{
    protected $costumerId;
    private $databaseConnection;

        public function __construct(dbh $database) {
            $this->databaseConnection = $database;
            var_dump($this->databaseConnection);
        }

        public function setCostumer($costumerId) {
            $this->costumerId = $costumerId;
        }
public function getItems(){
            try {

                $query = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE costumerId = :costumerId';

                //Execute
                $this->result = $this->databaseConnection->getRows($query, array(':costumerId' => $this->costumerId),'item');
                return $this->result;
            }
            catch(Exception $e) {
                var_dump($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit
this is the database connection class.

```
    class dbh {

            public $isConnected;
            public $connection;

        public function __construct()
        {
            try {
                $this->connection = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','username','password');
                $this->isConnected = true;
                var_dump($this->connection);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                $this->isConnected = false;
                throw new Exception ($e->getMessege());
            }
        }

public function getRows($query, $params=array(), $class = 'assoc') {
            try {
                $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
                $stmt->execute($params);
                if($class != 'assoc'){
                    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class);
                    return $stmt->fetchall();
                    }
                else {
                    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    return $stmt->fetchall(); 
                    }
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
     }
```

EDIT
i see now that im only getting the error when the next statment is there, i mean if i comment out the next statment after `$item = new item($dbh)` that is `$items->setCostumer(6);` im not getting the error,

EDIT:
ok i found that when i call the function getItems, or more spacificly the line `$this->result` is causing the error. but i still dont know why

Comment: Show the build of `$dbh`

Comment: value of $dbh where you passing?

Comment: Instentiation of tth database class is just `$dbh = new dbh;`

Comment: and in the dbh class its initiating a pdo object

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with the constructor. show actual (minimal!) code that reproduces the problem (minimal as in: you probably don't need a constructor to reproduce the problem. you probably don't need classes. etc. I would guess you only need about 3-5 lines of code.)

Comment: You better define that variable protected and global otherwise its of no use

Comment: @anwerjunaid No, when defined that way, a variable is set a public, so it's OK.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thats the funny thing about it. when i try to set the variable with a setter everything works just fine. it sjust somehow the constructer not taking the variable

Comment: I don't think it will solve your "error" but you have a typo : `throw new Exception ($e->getMessege());` Its "Message".

Comment: About your edit, that's exactly the point of @KarolyHorvath: Strip out all unnecessary code to isolate the real problem, which is not your constructor as you found out.

Comment: @jazZRo OK. Now I understand. But I have to go to work now. As soon as I'm coming home I'll start with that.

Comment: you seems to have another constructor somehwere without the argument

Comment: the error is saying the line of the constructer in item.php, so please explain

Answer (score 0):

I ran:

```
<?php

class item {
    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->db = $database;
        var_dump($this->db);
    }
}

class dbh {

    public $isConnected;
    public $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'password');
            $this->isConnected = true;
            var_dump($this->connection);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->isConnected = false;
            throw new Exception ($e->getMessege());
        }
    }
 }

$dbh = new dbh();

$item = new item($dbh);

?>
```

And it worked just fine...

```
object(PDO)#2 (0) {
}
object(dbh)#1 (2) {
["isConnected"]=>
bool(true)
["connection"]=>
object(PDO)#2 (0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you changed ?

Comment: Nothing - just copied OP's code and tested. Sorry! New here.

Comment: In this case - change nothing - it's better to comment (I know it's bad when you're new :D). Btw, I've more or less tried his code and no problem with it.

Comment: bit diffetent may be its the brackets dbh(); that were missing

Answer (score 0):

i don't know maybe you already did but did you include class files to your index.php?If you did what's the output of your var_dumps?
Maybe your db connection throws Exception and if you dont catch it it returns a Fatal Error and engine does not reach to item class can you please chcek your php error log

Comment: this is when i make `var_dump($dbh)` `object(dbh)#1 (2) { ["isConnected"]=> bool(true) ["connection"]=> object(PDO)#2 (0)`